# What time format is this and how do I convert it to a standardized dd/mm/yyyy date?

Tags: php, time, timestamp

I'm using the YouTube/Google API and for the upload date for a particular video a time/date formatted in the following format is returned:

`2012-05-16T17:15:29.000Z`

I'm not sure what format this is, but I'm wondering if there's an easy way (e.g. using `DateTime()`) to convert it to a format of dd/mm/yyyy?

Any mention of what the time format is called would be also appreciated ;).

Comment: ISO format : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Comment: i think it is similar 2012-05-16 5:15:29 pm

Comment: Actually the one Google/Youtube are using *is* the standardized one. Better yet, it has several advantages such as being able to use string sorting on the format for another nearly 8000 years and it is universally understood, while the `d/m/Y` format depends heavily on the context, culture and language :)

Comment: @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED OK jon skeet. lol

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That would be UTC time

```
date_format($date, 'd/m/Y');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just an additional note for anyone who doesn't know, `date_format()` needs a `DateTime()` object as the `$date` parameter. I'll accept when the timer drops.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to what @web_bod wrote, you can also do

`date('d/m/Y', strtotime('2012-05-16T17:15:29.000Z') );`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course there is.

```
$date = new DateTime("2012-05-16T17:15:29.000Z");
echo $date->format("d/m/Y");
```